# What is the meaning of array elements of *type_info variables in SOAP / WSDL auto-generated Apex classes?

Tags: apex, soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex

### Background:

As an example, let's put the `calculatorServices` class from the [Apex SOAP Callouts Trailhead Unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_soap_callouts) on the table. Considering any of the inner classes, for instance `doAdd`:

```
public class doAdd {
    public Double arg0;
    public Double arg1;
    private String[] arg0_type_info = new String[]{'arg0','http://calculator.services/',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] arg1_type_info = new String[]{'arg1','http://calculator.services/',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://calculator.services/','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'arg0','arg1'};
}
```

There are always 3 types of **type_info** variables:

- element-specific (`arg0_type_info`, `arg1_type_info` etc.)
- `apex_schema_type_info`
- `field_order_type_info`

All of these are described by elements of `String` arrays.

### Question:

Does anyone know what's the description/names/meanings of each of these array elements? I couldn't find anything among SF documentation, SF blogs or other SO posts.

### What I've got so far:

- first array element in `ELEMENT_type_info` is basically its name
- second array element in `ELEMENT_type_info` is either `tns` or `targetNamespace`
- first array element in `apex_schema_type_info` is either `tns` or `targetNamespace`
- `field_order_type_info` array's meaning is obvious

The reason behind my question is that due to WSDL2Apex generator limitations I'm forced to write my own Apex SOAP classes manually (inb4: yes, I saw FuseIT generator, it crashes for my WSDL). I have managed to write some basic (**and working!**) code already, but I'm not sure if leaving all these `null`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `'false'` values is fine or I should change some of them due to things I'm just not aware of.

Any help appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details are fairly well covered in [What are the parameters for the Salesforce WebServiceCallout.invoke method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4392616/54026)

From [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463751/54026):

> If the variable represents another XML element or a text node, then there needs to be a matching _type_info String[] e.g. bar_type_info. The elements of this array are:
>
> 1. XML element name
> 2. Schema
> 3. XML type
> 4. minOccurs
> 5. maxOccurs (set to '-1' for unbounded)
> 6. isNillable

If in doubt, Salesforce made their version of WSDL2Apex open source, so [you can see how it is setting the array elements](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex/blob/6f4e2a9d81e384721a976219d2636c977f6d03d6/src/main/java/com/salesforce/ide/wsdl2apex/core/ComplexTypeClass.java#L72).

```
private String typeInfo(Element element) {
    String elemNs =
            element.getRef() == null ? element.getSchema().getTargetNamespace() : element.getRef()
                    .getNamespaceURI();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("new String[]{");
    sb.append("'").append(element.getName()).append("'");
    sb.append(",'").append(elemNs).append("'");
    sb.append(",").append("null"); // Was the element's type, no longer used.
    sb.append(",'").append(element.getMinOccurs()).append("'");
    sb.append(",'").append(element.getMaxOccurs()).append("'");
    sb.append(",'").append(element.isNillable()).append("'");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```