# How to change FontSize Using Docusign's SOAP API and WSDL2Apex?

Tags: apex, soap-api, callout, docusign

Salesforce's WSDL2Apex tool skips big sections of [Docusign's WSDL file](https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi.wsdl), including all font information. I confirmed this with Docusign.

I recreated the FontSize enum as follows but it's not working. Can anyone point me to a successful Apex implementation of this WSDL or a suggestion for including a fontSize enum which successfully changes font size in custom tabs?

I've appended a snippet showing my Docusign call, which doesn't raise any exceptions but doesn't change the font, and my implementation of the fontsize enum.

```
    // recipient company tab...
    DocusigApi30.Tab companyNameTab = new DocusigApi30.Tab();
    companyNameTab.Type_x = 'Custom';
    companyNameTab.CustomTabType = 'Text';
    companyNameTab.CustomTabWidth = 175;
    companyNameTab.CustomTabHeight = 20;
    companyNameTab.FontSize = DocusigApi30.FontSize.Size18;
     ...

//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class DocusigApi30 {...

       public enum FontSize {Size7, Size8, Size9, Size10, Size11, Size12, Size14, Size16, Size18, Size20, Size22, 
                Size24, Size26, Size28, Size36, Size48, Size72}
    
        public class Tab {
            public Integer DocumentID;
            public Integer RecipientID;
            public Integer PageNumber;
            public Integer XPosition;
            public Integer YPosition;
            public Decimal ScaleValue;
            public DocusigApi30.AnchorTab AnchorTabItem;
            // -- skipped by WsDL2Apex 
            public String Font;
            public FontSize FontSize;
            public Integer MaxLength;
            public Integer TabOrder;
            // -- end skipped...
```

While changing to Docusign's REST API would solve the problem, it's a lot of work just to get a font size in a text block to match the rest of the document so I'm still hoping to find a way to implement fontsize in my generated class that works.

Comment: This can be done via [DocuSign's REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-envelope-tab-values/).

Answer (score 0):

After more scrutiny of Docusign's WSDLfile and the WSDL2Apex tool, I was able to change FontSize using the SOAP API in Salesforce as follows:

Edit your WSDL2Apex generated class inner Tab class to include the FontSize_type_info array and update the field_order_type_info array to include FontSize.

```
public class Tab {
        public String FontSize;
        ...
        private String[] FontSize_type_info = new String[]{'FontSize','http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'FontSize'...}
             }
```

Note that the order in field_order_type_info must follow your member variable declarations exactly. If your envelope doesn't send after you make a modification to your WSDL2Apex generated class, check your apex logs for errors. Making one change at a time makes this easier to debug.

In the Apex class where you create your Docusign Tab, you can use a String value for the enum.

```
companyNameTab.FontSize = 'Size36';
```

The permissable values can be found in [Docusign's WSDL file](https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?wsdl). The following post about WSDL2Apex pointed me in the right direction: [What is the meaning of array elements of *type_info variables in SOAP / WSDL auto-generated Apex classes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341038/what-is-the-meaning-of-array-elements-of-type-info-variables-in-soap-wsdl-aut)

In the appended image, I changed the FontSize for my company name tab to "Size36."
[image: Text Tab font changed to Size36]